# How I can check in react that an npm package's component loaded in the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I've created a component 'Home' in my application and installed a package - react-ckeditor-component which is providing a ck-editor to include React's component.

I've used the ckeditor from the package to my component   but when I've load the component the other content on the component loaded first but ckeditor taking some time.

I want to find a way through which I can check that the ckeditor component loaded into the DOM.

Example -

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import CKEditor from 'react-ckeditor-component';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    //State initialization
    this.state = {
      content: "Hello World"
    };
    this.setContent = this.setContent.bind(this)
  }

  //------ Test for race condition ------ //
  setContent(){
    console.log("Setting content");
    this.setState({
      content: "Hello World " + Math.random()
    })
  }

  onChange(evt){
    console.log("onChange fired with event info: ",evt, "and data: ",evt.editor.getData());
  }

  onBlur(evt){
    console.log("onBlur fired with event info: ",evt);
  }

  afterPaste(evt){
    console.log("afterPaste fired with event info: ",evt);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setContent()} children='Set content' />
        <CKEditor
          content={this.state.content}
          events={{
            blur: this.onBlur,
            afterPaste: this.afterPaste,
            change: this.onChange
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  document.getElementById('home')
);
```

Anybody can help me to find when the ckeditor loaded into the DOM?

Comment: Did you try onInit from ckeditor?

Comment: thanks @ducmai, but the oninit is not working.